# Importing modules implicit vs explicit

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I want to import the module `foo` and its submodule `foo.bar`. I can do that as follows:

```
import foo.bar
```

Now both `foo` and `foo.bar` are available as I want. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/import.html#searching) state this is due to `foo` being imported first:

> In this case, Python first tries to import `foo`, then `foo.bar`, and finally `foo.bar.baz`.

It wasn't clear to me that this was the way imports worked. Now that I know the following seems rather stupid:

```
import foo
import foo.bar
```

Is the single import clear enough for other programmers?

Comment: I think in general it is, but… That `import foo` declares that you’re going to use functions/types/constants out of `foo`, not just `foo.bar`. When the sub packages are closely related, this doesn’t add much information—if you imported `importlib.util` I won’t be surprised if you call `importlib` functions. But when they’re more independent, it is—using `os.path` doesn’t inherently imply that you’re going to use `os`.

Comment: How would `foo.bar` be available _without_ `foo` being available?

Answer (score 0):

The single import is not clear enough to run the program nicely. We need to specify clear instructions that from import packages what items we want to use.

You can also write it in this way,

```
import  foo
from foo import foo.bar
from foo import foo.bar.baz
```